# How to mock up a class for several tests in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that calls a remote service through HTTP. Right now, this class detects if it is running in "TESTING" mode and acts accordingly: while "TESTING" it does not send the actual request to the remote service, it simply returns without executing anything at all.

```
class PushService(object):

    def trigger_event(self, channel_name, event_name, data):
        if satnet_cfg.TESTING:
            logger.warning('[push] Service is in testing mode')
            return
        self._service.trigger(channel_name, event_name, data)
```

Several tests invoke parts of the code that end up by invoking this method. My questions are the following:

```
1. Do I have to patch this method/class for every test that, for some reason, also invoke that method?
2. Is it a good practice to try to patch it in the TestRunner?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do patch for all the tests you can do this in `setUpClass` method:

```
class RemoteServiceTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.patchers = []
        patcher = patch('application.PushService.trigger_event')
        cls.patchers.append(patcher)
        trigger_mock = patcher.start()
        trigger_mock.return_value = 'Some return value'

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        for patcher in cls.patchers:
            patcher.stop()

    def test1(self):
        # Test actions

    def test2(self):
        # Test actions

    def test3(self):
        # Test actions
```

`setUpClass` is called once per class (test suite in this case). Inside this method you can set all patchers that you need to be used by all tests.